# como aplanar un observable en RXJS y unirlo a otro obserbable para retornar una mezcla de ambos observable

Tags: array, nodejs, typescript, rxjs, observable

Cordial saludo.

Estoy aprendiendo RXJS y tengo una duda:

Como aplanar un vector para unirlo a un vector que ya es plano?

como unir estos 2 observables en 1 solo pero que retorne un vector con los elementos de ambos observables = [1, 'A',2, 'B',3 ,...]

```
let obv1 = of([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
let obv2 = of('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');
```

Lo que yo quiero es algo como meter ambos en un zip y que el resultado sea un unico vector con todos los elementos de obv1 y obv2

```
let u = zip(
 //Aplanar Obv1.pipe
 ,
 obv2
).pipe(
  //Operaciones
)
```

Comment: dependiendo de como quede la secuencia final hay varias opciones https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination si queres un zip [hay un ejemplo](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip#examples) bastante simple en la doc. forkjoin o mergeall  pueden ser alternativas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se hace a través del concatMap:

(A.Desempaquetado(),B).concat(zip)